# Error C2228 when constructing boost::function object in constructor argument list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, argument-passing, boost-function

The code below does not compile in Visual C++ 2005.

```
class SomeClass {
public: boost::function<void()> func;
        SomeClass(boost::function<void()> &func): func(func) { }
};

void someFunc() {
    std::cout << "someFunc" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    SomeClass sc(boost::function<void()>(&someFunc));
    sc.func(); // error C2228: left of '.func' must have class/struct/union
    return 0;
}
```

If I put parentheses around the argument to the SomeClass constructor or constructs the boost::function object outside the argument list it compiles fine.

```
    SomeClass sc((boost::function<void()>(&someFunc)));
    // or
    boost::function<void()> f(&someFunc);
    SomeClass sc(f);
```

What is the problem with the previous code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function declaration for a function taking a reference to a `boost:function <void()>` and returning a `SomeClass`. You can memorize the following rule, which turns out to apply to many other such disambiguation cases. You can find descriptions of these cases in section `8.2` of the C++ Standard.

> Any construct that could possibly be a declaration will be taken as a declaration

That means, the following will be taken as a parameter declaration, with superfluous parentheses

```
boost::function<void()>(&someFunc)
```

If you remove the parentheses, this will become clear

```
boost::function<void()> &someFunc
```

And thus, the whole declaration will not anymore declare an object, but a function

```
SomeClass sc(boost::function<void()> &someFunc);
```

To fix it, use the cast-notation

```
SomeClass sc((boost::function<void()>)&someFunc);
```

Or put parentheses around the whole expression, like you did.

Here is the Standard in all its glory from `8.2`:

> The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8 can also occur in the context of a declaration. In that context, the choice is between a function declaration with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter name and an object declaration with a function-style cast as the initializer. Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in 6.8, the resolution is to consider any construct that could possibly be a declaration a declaration. [Note: a declaration can be explicitly disambiguated by a nonfunction-style cast, by a = to indicate initialization or by removing the redundant parentheses around the parameter name. ]

Note that for controlling precedence, you are allowed to introduce parentheses just about anywhere, like in the following

```
int (((((((a))))))) = 3;
int (*(pa)) = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known as "C++'s Most Vexing Parse" (from [a book by Scott Meyers called Effective STL](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Effective-STL/Scott-Meyers/e/9780201749625)).

As [answered above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992717/error-c2228-when-constructing-boostfunction-object-in-constructor-argument-list/992724#992724), the compiler prefers to interpret the problematic line as a function declaration.